# Base URL for HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, url, path, hyperlink

I got a question and although I could find related information, I'm if it was exactly about what I'm wondering about.

The thing is, I got a site on `http://localhost/site`.
Now, when I create a link, let's say, `<a href="/posts">`, it links to `http://localhost/posts` instead of `http://localhost/site/posts`.
It works fine if I remove the slash (`<a href="posts">`), that would be the closest and maybe the easiest solution, but I'd like to know why the links ignore the folder where the file is at?

And I also would like to know if this can be fixed with .htaccess or something.

I've read that a link that begins with / makes it "absolute". So a link beginning with / is only intended to be used to link directly to the root, or to be used by sites stored at the root (in this case it wouldn't make much sense?) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leading '/' at the start of the URL informs the web browser that the path given is **absolute** (with respect to the web server root), i.e. if you link to `/posts` then you know that the resulting link will be to `http://www.mysite.com/posts`.

If you don't supply the leading '/' (and you don't give a complete url like `http://www.mysite.com/posts`) then usually the url is **relative**, and any page given will be relatvie to the page currently being viewed.

For example:

```
page being viewed               link url             target page
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
www.mysite.com/site              link.html            www.mysite.com/site/link.html
www.mysite.com/site              ../link.html         www.mysite.com/link.html
www.mysite.com/some/other/page   link.html            www.mysite.com/some/other/page/link.html
www.mysite.com/some/other/page   ../../../link.html   www.mysite.com/link.html
```

The decision on whether to use absolute or relative links is entirely up to you - the advantage of relative links is that if your site moves, links between pages on your site will still work correctly (for example if your site moves to `www.mysite.com/otherpath`, then any absolute links such `www.mysite.com/originalpath/home` will no longer work.

You should see the following site for a more complete explanation of relative urls:

- [Relative URLs (WebReference.com)](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html)

Comment: I have some code in JS in which all URLs start with a slash, but I don't have the site located in the root folder. So to make the URLs work correctly I have to add the base url of the site to all links? There's no other way? (or using the <base> tag, which I want to avoid using)

Comment: @renocor If you are constructing the link in JavaScript then you may want to consider constructing the URL from things like the `window.location` property.

Answer (score 0):

Your site root is `localhost` although you *assume* that `site` is your site root. When you use / it is relative to localhost as it is an absolute link.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it < a href="../posts" >

 ./ Means base directory, or home

 ../ Means one directory up

Comment: `./` means the _current_ directory, not the base.